# Converting an inputted string into a date

Tags: c#, parsing, date, readline

I have been trying to get a date conversion to wrok to convert from a string to a date I have looked at msdn and some other stack o questions but multiple ways have not worked. I am making a console app and it needs a valid date to check other dates. below is my current attempt.

```
string StartDate, EndDate;
Console.WriteLine("Input Start date");
StartDate = Console.ReadLine();
StartDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
```

I currently set the variable `StartDate` and then set it a value depending on what the user enters and then it should change this to a date using the `Parse`

Comment: Do you know the input format ?

Comment: In which format is your startdate?

Comment: Sounds like your format is not right. You can specify the format if needed, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8(v=vs.110).aspx . Secondly, you need to set your dates to the correct data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `string` is not a `DateTime` and a `DateTime` not a `String`. So you might be able to parse a string to a date but you cannot use the string variable for the DateTime and vice-versa. You need two variables:

```
string startDateInput = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse( startDateInput );
```

Since this could fail if the input string is not a valid date you should use `TryParse`:

```
DateTime startDate;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParse(startDateInput, out startDate);
if(validDate)
    Console.Write("Valid date: " + startDate.ToLongDateString());
```

Comment: jsut so i understand your method, it wokrs fine please expaplin this part for me
`DateTime.TryParse(startDateInput, out startDate);`
INB4 i am new to C#

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` is similar to `DateTime.Parse`. Both can parse a `String` to `DateTime` if it's a valid/supported format. But `Parse` throws an exception if the format is wrong whereas `TryParse` returns a `bool` which indicates whether it could be parsed or not. The `out` parameters returns the parsed `DateTime` on success. See MSDN for further informations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx

Answer (score 4):

you are trying to assign the `DateTime` value to string `StartDate`, which is wrong. So change it like below:

```
string StartDate, EndDate;
DateTime date;       
Console.WriteLine("Input Start date");
StartDate = Console.ReadLine();
date = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Convert.ToDateTime();`

Example:

```
string date = "01/08/2008";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(string)` method uses `DateTime.Parse(string)` explicitly. Since `DateTime.Parse` doesn't work in OP's code, that means `Convert.ToDateTime` method doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent and returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.

```
DateTime date;

if (!DateTime.TryParse("DateString", out date))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid string!");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Date Format.

**Try This:** Example format `MM-dd-yyyy`

```
Console.WriteLine("Input Start date Format -> MM-dd-yyyy");
string StartDate = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime YourDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate,"MM-dd-yyyy", 
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: This didn't work but what was this method trying to achieve, because i  am new and it would help if i understood it, i have never seen `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` before

Comment: you can use this method when you know the format upfront which user enters as input. for example if user enters date as `MM-dd-yyyy` then it parse the same as date using format `MM-dd-yyyy`, btw `did not work `means what was the problem? `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` willbe used when you want to parse the dates in `culture-independent`

Comment: i see what you mean, i think it was a syntax error so i'm just going over it now :)

Comment: you need to import `using System.Globalization;` namespace or check my edited answer.